# Customize Owl Carousel in Wordpress

Tags: javascript, wordpress, carousel

I am using the Morrison Hotel Wordpress theme. it takes Owl Carousel into account for the mid-page carousel.

Currently, I have one photo centered but 2 others on the sides, as you can see in the following screenshot:

[Carousel screen cap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v5WO4.jpg)

However, I would like to have a single image. Of course, I want the images to continue scrolling but one by one.

The theme loads the morrison-hotel.min.js compressed version and I found in this file the call to owl carousel:

```
carousel:function(){if(jQuery().owlCarousel){var t=e(".morrison-hotel-carousel");t.owlCarousel({center:t.data("center"),loop:!0,autoplay:!0,nav:!1,responsive:{0:{items:1},768:{items:t.data("cols")}}})}}
```

How do I change it to do what I want?
Do you have an idea, or any clues please? I am a beginner so what seems obvious to you will not necessarily be obvious to me, if you can explain it clearly that would be great. Thank you

Thank you for your time and help.

```js
carousel:function(){if(jQuery().owlCarousel){var t=e(".morrison-hotel-carousel");t.owlCarousel({center:t.data("center"),loop:!0,autoplay:!0,nav:!1,responsive:{0:{items:1},768:{items:t.data("cols")}}})}}
```

```css
#page-carousel .owl-controls {
  display: none;
}

#page-carousel .has-booking-form .owl-controls {
  bottom: 4.5em;
}

#page-carousel img {
  filter: grayscale(0);
  transition: filter 0.2s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.2, 1);
}

#page-carousel .owl-item:hover img {
  filter: grayscale(1);
}

.no-js #page-carousel .morrison-hotel-carousel {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.no-js #page-carousel .morrison-hotel-carousel > div {
  display: none;
}

.no-js #page-carousel .morrison-hotel-carousel > div:nth-child(-n+3) {
  display: table-cell;
}

.owl-carousel {
  display: none;
  width: 100%;
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
  /* position relative and z-index fix webkit rendering fonts issue */
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}

.owl-carousel .owl-stage {
  position: relative;
  -ms-touch-action: pan-Y;
}

.owl-carousel .owl-stage:after {
  content: ".";
  display: block;
  clear: both;
  visibility: hidden;
  line-height: 0;
  height: 0;
}

.owl-carousel .owl-stage-outer {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  /* fix for flashing background */
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px);
}

.owl-carousel .owl-item {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 1px;
  float: left;
  /*-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;*/
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
  -webkit-touch-callout: none;
}

.owl-carousel .owl-item img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

.owl-carousel .owl-nav.disabled,
.owl-carousel .owl-dots.disabled {
  display: none;
}

.owl-carousel .owl-nav .owl-prev,
.owl-carousel .owl-nav .owl-next,
.owl-carousel .owl-dot {
  cursor: pointer;
  cursor: hand;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}

.owl-carousel.owl-loaded {
  display: block;
}

.owl-carousel.owl-loading {
  opacity: 0;
  display: block;
}

.owl-carousel.owl-hidden {
  opacity: 0;
}

.owl-carousel.owl-refresh .owl-item {
  display: none;
}

.owl-carousel.owl-drag .owl-item {
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}

.owl-carousel.owl-grab {
  cursor: move;
  cursor: -webkit-grab;
  cursor: grab;
}

.owl-carousel.owl-rtl {
  direction: rtl;
}

.owl-carousel.owl-rtl .owl-item {
  float: right;
}

.owl-carousel .owl-controls {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 2em;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 5;
}

.owl-carousel .owl-dots {
  text-align: center;
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
}

.owl-carousel .owl-dots .owl-dot {
  display: inline-block;
  zoom: 1;
  *display: inline;
}

.owl-carousel .owl-dots .owl-dot span {
  width: 11px;
  height: 11px;
  margin: 5px 7px;
  background: #fff;
  display: block;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: visible;
  transition-duration: 0.2s;
  transition-property: opacity, background-color;
  transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.2, 1);
  border-radius: 100%;
}

.owl-carousel .owl-dots .owl-dot.active span,
.owl-carousel .owl-dots .owl-dot:hover span {
  background: #c19c78;
}

/* No Js */

.no-js .owl-carousel {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div id="page-carousel" wfd-id="76">
    <div class="owl-carousel morrison-hotel-carousel owl-theme owl-center owl-loaded" data-cols="2" data-center="true" wfd-id="77">
        <div class="owl-stage-outer" wfd-id="103">
            <div class="owl-stage" style="transition: all 0.25s ease 0s; width: 6013px; transform: translate3d(-1503px, 0px, 0px);" wfd-id="104">
                <div class="owl-item cloned" style="width: 429.5px; margin-right: 0px;" wfd-id="131">
                    <div wfd-id="132">
                        <img src="https://hotel-restaurant-la-borie.fr/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/20171012_145725-815x500.jpg" width="815" height="500" srcset="https://hotel-restaurant-la-borie.fr/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/20171012_145725-815x500.jpg 815w, https://hotel-restaurant-la-borie.fr/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/20171012_145725-1140x699.jpg 1140w, https://hotel-restaurant-la-borie.fr/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/20171012_145725-480x294.jpg 480w, https://hotel-restaurant-la-borie.fr/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/20171012_145725-320x196.jpg 320w" sizes="(max-width: 815px) 100vw, 815px" alt="">
                    </div></div><div class="owl-item cloned" style="width: 429.5px; margin-right: 0px;" wfd-id="129"><div wfd-id="130">
                        <img src="https://hotel-restaurant-la-borie.fr/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/DSCF2250-815x500.jpg" width="815" height="500" srcset="https://hotel-restaurant-la-borie.fr/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/DSCF2250-815x500.jpg 815w, https://hotel-restaurant-la-borie.fr/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/DSCF2250-1140x699.jpg 1140w, https://hotel-restaurant-la-borie.fr/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/DSCF2250-480x294.jpg 480w, https://hotel-restaurant-la-borie.fr/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/DSCF2250-320x196.jpg 320w" sizes="(max-width: 815px) 100vw, 815px" alt="">
                    </div></div><div class="owl-item" style="width: 429.5px; margin-right: 0px;" wfd-id="127"><div wfd-id="128">
                        <img src="https://hotel-restaurant-la-borie.fr/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/20180622_103809-815x500.jpg" width="815" height="500" srcset="https://hotel-restaurant-la-borie.fr/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/20180622_103809-815x500.jpg 815w, https://hotel-restaurant-la-borie.fr/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/20180622_103809-1140x699.jpg 1140w, https://hotel-restaurant-la-borie.fr/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/20180622_103809-480x294.jpg 480w, https://hotel-restaurant-la-borie.fr/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/20180622_103809-320x196.jpg 320w" sizes="(max-width: 815px) 100vw, 815px" alt="">
                    </div></div><div class="owl-item" style="width: 429.5px; margin-right: 0px;" wfd-id="125"><div wfd-id="126">
                        <img src="https://hotel-restaurant-la-borie.fr/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/20180622_104005-815x500.jpg" width="815" height="500" srcset="https://hotel-restaurant-la-borie.fr/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/20180622_104005-815x500.jpg 815w, https://hotel-restaurant-la-borie.fr/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/20180622_104005-1140x699.jpg 1140w, https://hotel-restaurant-la-borie.fr/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/20180622_104005-480x294.jpg 480w, https://hotel-restaurant-la-borie.fr/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/20180622_104005-320x196.jpg 320w" sizes="(max-width: 815px) 100vw, 815px" alt="">
                    </div></div><div class="owl-item active center" style="width: 429.5px; margin-right: 0px;" wfd-id="123"><div wfd-id="124">
                        <img src="https://hotel-restaurant-la-borie.fr/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/20180325_111721-815x500.jpg" width="815" height="500" srcset="https://hotel-restaurant-la-borie.fr/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/20180325_111721-815x500.jpg 815w, https://hotel-restaurant-la-borie.fr/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/20180325_111721-1140x699.jpg 1140w, https://hotel-restaurant-la-borie.fr/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/20180325_111721-480x294.jpg 480w, https://hotel-restaurant-la-borie.fr/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/20180325_111721-320x196.jpg 320w" sizes="(max-width: 815px) 100vw, 815px" alt="">
                    </div></div><div class="owl-item active" style="width: 429.5px; margin-right: 0px;" wfd-id="121"><div wfd-id="122">
                        <img src="https://hotel-restaurant-la-borie.fr/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/20180623_092543-815x500.jpg" width="815" height="500" srcset="https://hotel-restaurant-la-borie.fr/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/20180623_092543-815x500.jpg 815w, https://hotel-restaurant-la-borie.fr/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/20180623_092543-1140x699.jpg 1140w, https://hotel-restaurant-la-borie.fr/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/20180623_092543-480x294.jpg 480w, https://hotel-restaurant-la-borie.fr/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/20180623_092543-320x196.jpg 320w" sizes="(max-width: 815px) 100vw, 815px" alt="">
                    </div></div><div class="owl-item" style="width: 429.5px; margin-right: 0px;" wfd-id="119"><div wfd-id="120">
                        <img src="https://hotel-restaurant-la-borie.fr/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/20180622_142800-815x500.jpg" width="815" height="500" srcset="https://hotel-restaurant-la-borie.fr/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/20180622_142800-815x500.jpg 815w, https://hotel-restaurant-la-borie.fr/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/20180622_142800-1140x699.jpg 1140w, https://hotel-restaurant-la-borie.fr/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/20180622_142800-480x294.jpg 480w, https://hotel-restaurant-la-borie.fr/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/20180622_142800-320x196.jpg 320w" sizes="(max-width: 815px) 100vw, 815px" alt="">
                    </div></div><div class="owl-item" style="width: 429.5px; margin-right: 0px;" wfd-id="117"><div wfd-id="118">
                        <img src="https://hotel-restaurant-la-borie.fr/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/DSCF2250-1-815x500.jpg" width="815" height="500" srcset="https://hotel-restaurant-la-borie.fr/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/DSCF2250-1-815x500.jpg 815w, https://hotel-restaurant-la-borie.fr/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/DSCF2250-1-1140x699.jpg 1140w, https://hotel-restaurant-la-borie.fr/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/DSCF2250-1-480x294.jpg 480w, https://hotel-restaurant-la-borie.fr/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/DSCF2250-1-320x196.jpg 320w" sizes="(max-width: 815px) 100vw, 815px" alt="">
                    </div></div><div class="owl-item" style="width: 429.5px; margin-right: 0px;" wfd-id="115"><div wfd-id="116">
                        <img src="https://hotel-restaurant-la-borie.fr/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/20180622_103255-815x500.jpg" width="815" height="500" srcset="https://hotel-restaurant-la-borie.fr/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/20180622_103255-815x500.jpg 815w, https://hotel-restaurant-la-borie.fr/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/20180622_103255-1140x699.jpg 1140w, https://hotel-restaurant-la-borie.fr/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/20180622_103255-480x294.jpg 480w, https://hotel-restaurant-la-borie.fr/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/20180622_103255-320x196.jpg 320w" sizes="(max-width: 815px) 100vw, 815px" alt="">
                    </div></div><div class="owl-item" style="width: 429.5px; margin-right: 0px;" wfd-id="113"><div wfd-id="114">
                        <img src="https://hotel-restaurant-la-borie.fr/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/20171012_151156-815x500.jpg" width="815" height="500" srcset="https://hotel-restaurant-la-borie.fr/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/20171012_151156-815x500.jpg 815w, https://hotel-restaurant-la-borie.fr/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/20171012_151156-1140x699.jpg 1140w, https://hotel-restaurant-la-borie.fr/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/20171012_151156-480x294.jpg 480w, https://hotel-restaurant-la-borie.fr/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/20171012_151156-320x196.jpg 320w" sizes="(max-width: 815px) 100vw, 815px" alt="">
                    </div></div><div class="owl-item" style="width: 429.5px; margin-right: 0px;" wfd-id="111"><div wfd-id="112">
                        <img src="https://hotel-restaurant-la-borie.fr/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/20171012_145725-815x500.jpg" width="815" height="500" srcset="https://hotel-restaurant-la-borie.fr/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/20171012_145725-815x500.jpg 815w, https://hotel-restaurant-la-borie.fr/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/20171012_145725-1140x699.jpg 1140w, https://hotel-restaurant-la-borie.fr/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/20171012_145725-480x294.jpg 480w, https://hotel-restaurant-la-borie.fr/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/20171012_145725-320x196.jpg 320w" sizes="(max-width: 815px) 100vw, 815px" alt="">
                    </div></div><div class="owl-item" style="width: 429.5px; margin-right: 0px;" wfd-id="109"><div wfd-id="110">
                        <img src="https://hotel-restaurant-la-borie.fr/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/DSCF2250-815x500.jpg" width="815" height="500" srcset="https://hotel-restaurant-la-borie.fr/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/DSCF2250-815x500.jpg 815w, https://hotel-restaurant-la-borie.fr/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/DSCF2250-1140x699.jpg 1140w, https://hotel-restaurant-la-borie.fr/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/DSCF2250-480x294.jpg 480w, https://hotel-restaurant-la-borie.fr/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/DSCF2250-320x196.jpg 320w" sizes="(max-width: 815px) 100vw, 815px" alt="">
                    </div></div><div class="owl-item cloned" style="width: 429.5px; margin-right: 0px;" wfd-id="107"><div wfd-id="108">
                        <img src="https://hotel-restaurant-la-borie.fr/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/20180622_103809-815x500.jpg" width="815" height="500" srcset="https://hotel-restaurant-la-borie.fr/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/20180622_103809-815x500.jpg 815w, https://hotel-restaurant-la-borie.fr/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/20180622_103809-1140x699.jpg 1140w, https://hotel-restaurant-la-borie.fr/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/20180622_103809-480x294.jpg 480w, https://hotel-restaurant-la-borie.fr/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/20180622_103809-320x196.jpg 320w" sizes="(max-width: 815px) 100vw, 815px" alt="">
                    </div></div><div class="owl-item cloned" style="width: 429.5px; margin-right: 0px;" wfd-id="105"><div wfd-id="106">
                        <img src="https://hotel-restaurant-la-borie.fr/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/20180622_104005-815x500.jpg" width="815" height="500" srcset="https://hotel-restaurant-la-borie.fr/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/20180622_104005-815x500.jpg 815w, https://hotel-restaurant-la-borie.fr/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/20180622_104005-1140x699.jpg 1140w, https://hotel-restaurant-la-borie.fr/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/20180622_104005-480x294.jpg 480w, https://hotel-restaurant-la-borie.fr/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/20180622_104005-320x196.jpg 320w" sizes="(max-width: 815px) 100vw, 815px" alt="">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="owl-controls" wfd-id="78">
            <div class="owl-nav" wfd-id="100">
                <div class="owl-prev" style="display: none;" wfd-id="102">prev</div>
                <div class="owl-next" style="display: none;" wfd-id="101">next</div>
            </div>
            <div class="owl-dots" style="" wfd-id="79">
                <div class="owl-dot" wfd-id="98">
                    <span wfd-id="99"></span></div>
                    <div class="owl-dot" wfd-id="96"><span wfd-id="97"></span></div>
                    <div class="owl-dot active" wfd-id="94"><span wfd-id="95"></span></div>
                    <div class="owl-dot" wfd-id="92"><span wfd-id="93"></span></div>
                    <div class="owl-dot" wfd-id="90"><span wfd-id="91"></span></div>
                    <div class="owl-dot" wfd-id="88"><span wfd-id="89"></span></div>
                    <div class="owl-dot" wfd-id="86"><span wfd-id="87"></span></div>
                    <div class="owl-dot" wfd-id="84"><span wfd-id="85"></span></div>
                    <div class="owl-dot" wfd-id="82"><span wfd-id="83"></span></div>
                    <div class="owl-dot" wfd-id="80"><span wfd-id="81"></span></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Can you look in your browser's dev tools and inspect the carousel images. They may have some obvious CSS selectors associated with them. It would help if you could post the HTML of the carousel.

Comment: I think simple CSS code fix the same, no need to update the JS code for it

Comment: according to theme setup might be settings into the backend to changes values https://prnt.sc/w58rdt, and these surly update the look and size of images as well

Comment: Thanks for answers I add the snippet if you want to take a look at it to tell me what you think. I'm checking your link.

Comment: I am pretty sure, there are backend settings to change it, you need just find it.

Comment: Here is another demo http://demo.lollum.com/morrisonhotelv3/ where slider into a full single with slide, and when you check it the data attribute is set to false.
so it means backend settings to change it. https://prnt.sc/w5by4l

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the js is using `t.data("cols")` as a variable to set the number of 'items' on devices greater than 768px. You can also see that it's set to 1 at lower widths. This to me, implies that there is a variable that can be set but looking at the instruction videos (found the theme on Themeforest), there may not be a place to set this in your theme.

You could try edit the js to set items:1 for the wider screen width: `768:{items:1}`

Edit: Be careful here, this will likely change ALL carousels on your site to 1 item.

Have you reached out to the theme developer, my experience is they're usually pretty good with providing assistance like this?

Comment: thank you for answering, I'm gonna try your idea. No I haven't dare contact the developpers. I didn't think it was possible

Comment: I've tried 768:{items:1} and it doesn"t change anything

Comment: I've succeeded changing 768:{items:1}  in morrison.js and not morrison.min.js and than changin the call of the file in funcitons.php  thanks a lot !